# How do I escape a single quote inside single quotes in jenkins-pipeline bash command

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, quotes

in jenkins-pipeline, I'm trying to use SED to append the following line to the end of a file.

```
sh "sed -i '\$ s/\$/ public_file=\\/var\\/lib\\/jenkins\\/workspace\\/test-project\\ ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'  /' file.txt"
```

but I can't figure out how to escape the below line in my Jenkins file to make it work.

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

I've already tried the following, which works in katacoda playground, but not in jenkins pipeline.

```
'"'"'-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"'"'  /' file.txt
```

Comment: I don't know anything about jenkins-pipeline, but if you *weren't* using it, I would suggest `cat >>yourfile <<'EOF'`, then the line you want to append, then a line containing `EOF`, as a solution that works 100% of the time.

Comment: That said, if you get rid of the space after the `-o` and before the option, then you don't need quotes at all! That is, `ansible_ssh_common_args=-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` should be entirely equivalent.

Comment: Note that if the pattern you are looking for contains `/`, you can use an alternate delimiter for sed.  eg `sed -e 's@/some/path/@/replacement@g` . Much cleaner than escaping the `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `"` to wrap sed command, then you can use `'` in command directly without to escape it.
2. use `@`, but `/` as delimiter for sed `s` command, then you no need to escape the `/` appeared in file path to make the whole commend more concise and readable.

```sh
sed -i "\$ s@\$@ public_file=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-project ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'  @" file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, you cannot escape single quotes within single quotes.

See the [bash manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

You can **use double quotes** instead; then escape them as needed. You can then use single quotes within them without further escaping.